# Adding attributre label and attribute option value label to get cart rest api in magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, api

Hi I want to add attribute label and attribute option value label to Magento 2 Guest cart REST API response like below screen shot by overriding default magento 2 files.

https://prnt.sc/i73dxm

Please help to me

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
POST 
http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/carts/guest-cart-id/items
Header    Authorization  Bearer {token}
Body
{
"cart_item": {
"quote_id": "{Cart ID}",
"sku": "WT09",                            
"qty": 1,"product_option": {
"extension_attributes": {
"configurable_item_options": [
{
"option_id": "93",  //This is for color, you can edit
"option_value":57,
"extension_attributes": {}
},
{
"option_id": "141",   //This is for size, you can edit
"option_value":167,
"extension_attributes": {}
}
]
}
},
"extension_attributes": {}
}
```

}